# How to add a link of a local file on Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: windows, google-sheets, directory, path

I want to add a link of a local file to a cell on Google Spreadsheet. I tried to use "insert Link" and pasted a full path of the file I want like `C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\xxxxxx\xxxx.cpp`.
However, it says,
`Link doesn't look right. Typo?`
Is it not possible to add a link of local path?

Answer (score 0):

When I open a local file with a browser, the link starts with

> file:///C:/(....)/

because you acces a local file with no network protocol. Maybe you can put the file into the same directory and use relative links.

Sure you know that you won't be able to access that file from the web without further actions relating your internet connection.

In this case, you might need to setup a http-Server;
use Windows' IIS (internet information services);
or just rent a hosting server.

Have fun!

Edit: This might also be useful:

> HYPERLINK Creates a hyperlink inside a cell.
>
> Sample Usage HYPERLINK("http://www.google.com/","Google")
>
> Syntax HYPERLINK(url, [link_label])
>
> https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?hl=en

Comment: Thank you. I just forgot it was necessary to setup a http-server to get access to my computer from the Internet. I will try.

Comment: You can configure some cloud servers to use then as ftp or http, too.